# iOS push notification willPresent notification delegate method is not calling when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented the push notification in the app. I am getting callbacks on the following delegate method whenever the push comes.

```
func application(_: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

I have implemented the following delegate method To show the push notification when the app is in the foreground.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    { 
       completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

Unfortunately, it is not working every time. Irrespective of the app state I'm getting the callback on **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method. Is there any particular reason for this behavior? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the `userNotificationCenter` with the "`didReceive response`" signature instead of the `application(didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:..)`

```
// MARK: Notification handling

// If the app is in the background
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let id = response.notification.request.identifier
    print("Received notification with ID = \(id)")

    completionHandler()
}

// If the app is in the foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let id = notification.request.identifier
    print("Received notification with ID = \(id)")

    completionHandler([.sound, .alert])
}
```

Also have your AppDelegate be UNUserNotificationCenter delegate.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
.
.
.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I did a double check on setting the delegate and found that it was not set as expected. But it still confuses me why I'm getting a callback on didReceiveRemoteNotification method even the delegate was not set. I completely ignored the delegate check because of that. Anyway thanks a lot.